# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestSequenceFunctions'

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm working on unittest in python.

I'm working on a Ububtu machine from  "/home/jamy/PycharmProjects/xcxzc/UnitTesting.py" directory and trying to run this following code:

```
import unittest

class LearningCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_starting_out(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

def main():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "unitTesting.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "/home/jamy/PycharmProjects/xcxzc/unittest.py", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestSequenceFunctions'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By naming your script `unittest.py` you are shadowing the built-in `unittest` module.

Comment: @ZahidulIslamJamy ok, but what about `/home/jamy/PycharmProjects/xcxzc/unittest.py`? Python imports this, instead of built-in `unittest`.

Comment: problem fixed! :) initially i created a file unittest.py though i already deleted this file unexpectedly it remains in my directory. thank you

Comment: @ZahidulIslamJamy that's what I've actually meant. Glad you solved it. Don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks.